# client server c++

Tags: visual-c++, client-server

I try to build a client server connection, I have tried to send data from client and receive by server.
I modify program from the internet, but the result are not satisfy. The connection between client and server is establish, but the client can not send the data to the server.

Can some body tell me what is wrong with these programs?

server

```
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 SOCKADDR_IN addr;
 SOCKET sListen;
 SOCKET sConnect;
 SOCKET Connections;

 int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
 int ConCounter = 0;
 struct Buffer
{
char Message[256];
};


int InitWinSock()
{
int RetVal = 0;
WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);

return RetVal;
}

 int main()
 {
int RetVal = 0;
RetVal = InitWinSock();
if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    exit(1);
}

Connections = (SOCKET)calloc(1, sizeof(SOCKET));
sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

listen(sListen, 1); 

for(;; Sleep(50))
{
    if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
    {
        cout<<"connection was found";

        for(;; Sleep(50))
{
        Buffer sbuffer;
        char* Recv = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);      
        if(recv(Connections, Recv, 256, NULL))
        {       
            cout<<Recv<<endl;           
            ZeroMemory(Recv, 256);
        }
        }               
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

client:

```
 #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
 #include <WinSock2.h>
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 SOCKADDR_IN addr;

 SOCKET sConnect;

 struct Buffer
{

char Message[256];
};

 int main()
{
system("cls");

int RetVal = 0;

WSAData wsaData;
WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
RetVal = WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData);
if(RetVal != 0)
{                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    exit(1);
}

sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

cout << "Connect to Masterserver? [ENTER]" <<endl;
getchar();
RetVal = connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

if(RetVal != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not connect to server", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    main();
}
else
{

    cout << "Connected" <<endl;


    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        char* buffer = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 256);

        cin >> buffer;
        getchar();

        send(sConnect, buffer, 256, NULL);
    }
}

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In the server, why do you set SConnect to a value that you then overwrite with a different value? That leaks sockets! You allocate a new receive buffer on each pass in the loop which you never free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`recv(Connections` should be `recv(sConnect`. See my comment to your question for a list of other, more minor, bugs in your code.